# Change DateTime format in XML generated by SQL Server

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008-r2, for-xml-path

I am creating XML from SQL Server database tables, using for XML path to generate a node for each column in the table. I need to be able to store any DateTime column a format like "02/15/2016 07:39:45 PM" instead of the standard "2016-02-15T07:39:45" format. This needs to be flexible enough to make the change to any DateTime column in the database, some tables have more of these columns than others, but, if it helps, every column name for a DateTime columns ends with "_DT". So, Ideally, the XML returned would have the formatting applied to any DateTime field, regardless of its position, and how many are included

Comment: Could you please elaborate the question

Comment: If the For XML Path query returns a node formatted like <Sale_Date>2016-02-15T07:39:45</Sale_Date> I need it to look like <Sale_Date>02/15/2016 07:39:45 PM</Sale_Date> instead. There could be any combination of DateTime nodes, but they should all be formatted the same.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you might need to convert the datetime data type value into varchar data type in order to display the date value to a format which you wanted.